# Performance interaction in SCORM

Tags: performance, interaction, scorm, scorm2004

I understood almost all types of interactions specified by the scorm data model element **cmi.interactions.n.type**(true_false, multiple_choice, fill_in, long_fill_in, matching, performance, sequencing, likert, numeric, other) ,it remains to understand the type performance. I found an explanation of Ostyn but it remains ambiguous .

> The Performance interaction is the most flexible and rich of the
>   standard interaction types in SCORM. It allows the capture of a number
>   of arbitrary steps performed by a learner, along with information
>   about every step. (Claud Ostyn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it does exactly that, i.e. stores arbitrary data related to an ambiguous non-standard interaction (e.g. a 3D simulation). LMS are not supposed to do anything with interaction data anyway, at least not regarding completion and grading, so it is mostly used by instructional designers who need a deeper insight into what the learners are doing and then adjust the training, e.g. exercise difficulty.